# Create file in netbeans platform

Tags: performance, file, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I've made a plugin for NetBeans which parse a Java file and generate 2 files. I'm writting it to the disk with standard operations (i.e., normal java.io.File). It works, but it takes a while (usually 10 seconds or +) to show on the project (folder) tree.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to create this file using the netbeans platform api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FileSystem AP](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-filesystems/org/openide/filesystems/package-summary.html)I is the place that you should probably start.  You may want to focus on the [FileObject](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-filesystems/org/openide/filesystems/FileObject.html) and [FileUtil](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-filesystems/org/openide/filesystems/FileUtil.html) classes.